# whatever I try to delete the top item get deleted every-time from my database?

Tags: php, mysqli, delete-row

Here is the code for fetching all items form database:

```
     $result = queryMysql("SELECT postid,posttitle FROM userpost WHERE   userid=$userid");
    $postid = -1;
    $title = "No items.";
    if($result->num_rows){
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
            $postid = $row['postid'];
            $title = $row['posttitle'];

     echo <<<_END
            <div class="panel panel-default " style="-webkit-border-radius:0 ;-moz-border-radius:0 ;border-radius: 0; margin-top: 10px;">
                                <div class="panel-body panel-body-custom">
                                    <a href="userpost.php?postid=$postid" class="item-title col-xs-10"> <h5  class="text-overflow-elipsis" style="width: 100%;">$title
                                    </h5></a><span class="col-xs-2 btn btn-default glyphicon glyphicon-trash" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"></span>


        <!-- delete confirmation window -->

            <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog">

      <!-- Modal content-->
            <div class="modal-content text-center">

               <div class="modal-body">
                 <h4>Are you sure you want to delete?</h4>
                  <a href="delete.php?postid=$postid" class="btn btn-warning">**Delete**</a>
               </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div> 


     _END;
           }
```

Here is the php code for deletion:

```
    session_start();
require_once 'functions.php';
//echo "Post id is ".$_GET['postid']; everytime getting the topmost id why?

if($_SESSION['loggedin']){
    $postid = $_GET['postid'];
    $uid = $_SESSION['user_id'];
    $result = queryMysql("DELETE FROM userpost WHERE postid = $postid and userid = $uid");
    if($result) {
        header('location: profile.php');
    }else{
        echo "Can not delete. <a href='profile.php' class='btn btn-primary'>Go back</a>";
    }
}
```

So when I am clicking the delete button it is deleting the top most item.Why it is not deleting the item I am selecting? How can I delete my desired item?Please help.

Comment: How many records are shown on the first page? Have you confirmed that `$postid` is set correctly on the delete buttons?

Comment: All records are shown on one page. I mentioned the delete button in my code above, I think it's ok.